# Monkey-Patching Magic Methods on scikit-learn Class Instance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, monkeypatching, magic-methods

I'm trying to build a factory class called `SafeModel`, whose `generate` method accepts an *instance* of a scikit-learn class, changes some of its properties, and returns the same instance. Specifically, for this example, I'd like to access the `coef_` property of the returned model and in Case 1) if the underlying scikit-learn class contains `coef_`, then return that class' `coef_`, and in Case 2) if the underlying scikit-learn class contains `feature_importances_`, return that class' `feature_importances`.

I've had success monkey-patching attributes of an instance of a Python class. I've had less success monkey-patching magic methods of an instance of a Python class. The caveat with my case is: the attributes `coef_` and `feature_importances` are never defined at scikit-learn class instantiation time; instead, they are only defined after the `fit` method is called on their respective classes. For this reason, I can't override the attribute definition itself.

```
from types import MethodType


class SafeModel:

    FALLBACK_ATTRIBUTES = {
        'coef_': ['feature_importances_'],
    }

    @classmethod
    def generate(cls, model):
        safe_model = cls._secure_attributes(model)
        return safe_model

    @classmethod
    def _secure_attributes(cls, model):
        def __secure_getattr__(self, name):
            for fallback_attribute in cls.FALLBACK_ATTRIBUTES[name]:
                try:
                    return getattr(self, fallback_attribute)
                except:
                    continue
        model.__getattr__ = MethodType(__secure_getattr__, model)
        return model


    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

    model = SafeModel.generate(RandomForestClassifier())
    model.coef_  # AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to pinpoint what was wrong with your code. I found a workaroung that may work for your use case though.
I'm using a different strategy as I'm just using `SafeModel.__getattr__` as a wrapper around the model's `getattr` method instead of monkey patching.

```
from sklearn.utils.validation import NotFittedError
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

class SafeModel(object):

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.FALLBACK_ATTRIBUTES = {
        'coef_': ['feature_importances_'],
    }
        self.model = model

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self.model, name)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        for fallback_attribute in self.FALLBACK_ATTRIBUTES[name]:
            try:
                return getattr(self.model, fallback_attribute)
            except NotFittedError as e:
                # NotFittedError inherits AttributeError.
                raise e
            except AttributeError:
                continue
        else:
            raise AttributeError(
                "{} object has no attribute {}.".format(
                    self.__class__.__name__, name) + 
                " Could not retrieve any fallback attribute.")                    


model = SafeModel(RandomForestClassifier())
model.coef_
```

Output:

```
NotFittedError: Estimator not fitted, call `fit` before `feature_importances_`.
```

Note that this is the normal behavior, as you mentioned you can't access `feature_importances_` until you've fit the random forest.

Admittedly the exception catching is rather fragile here (you'd need to add a bunch of Exceptions that are likely to be raised), but if you don't care about raising the proper exception when trying to access attributes that should be fine.

Let me know if that works for you. If you find out what's going on with the code you posted I would be interested in an explanation as well!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm hoping to use ```SafeModel``` as a factory, like ```model = SafeModel.generate(RandomForestClassifier())```, which returns a modified instance of the sk-learn object. Above, we're left with an instance of ```SafeModel``` instead.

Comment: Couldn't you then use it as a decorator ? Then your models are not `SafeModel` instances, but are decorated wit the `__getattr__`

Comment: @cavaunpeu Ok. FYI I tried to put print statements in your "__secure_getattr__", they are never shown. I was not able to apply even a simple decorator on __getattr__.  Challensois: if you can do that I'd love to see a solution.

Comment: @user3914041 I tried the same to no avail. I think Python calls magic method in a fundamentally different way than it calls non-magic methods (by accessing the relevant instance's __dict__ attribute).

Comment: @cavaunpeu Probably, I was able to overwrite fit using your code. Could not get the magic method to work though.